# Making a image slider but the last image ends without looping

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a image slider but the when its time for the last image, image slider only shows 2 images except of showing the image next in line. All I want is the first image to show up in line instead of shrinking down to two images when the slider is as its last image.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

As seen in Image 2, instead of showing the upcoming 'Number 1' image, the slider just ends but if button is pressed, image slider works normally starting from the first image. Same problem occurs while  sliding to previous image too.

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/testfiles/styles1.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="btn " id="btn-prev" onclick="">&#10094</span>
      <div class="slide">
        <img id="left-image" src="/testfiles/image/1.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img id="center-image" src="/testfiles/image/2.png" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img id="right-image" src="/testfiles/image/3.png" alt="" />
      </div>
--      <span class="btn" id="btn-next" >&#10095</span>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/testfiles/app1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Js code:

```
var prev_btn = document.getElementById("btn-prev");
var next_btn = document.getElementById("btn-next");
var center_image = document.getElementById("center-image");
var left_image = document.getElementById("left-image");
var right_image = document.getElementById("right-image");

var image_array = [
  "/testfiles/image/1.png",
  "/testfiles/image/2.png",
  "/testfiles/image/3.png",
  "/testfiles/image/4.png",
  "/testfiles/image/5.png",
];

var count = 0;

next_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count++;
  left_image.src = image_array[count - 1];

  if (count > image_array.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
  }
  right_image.src = image_array[count + 1];
  center_image.src = image_array[count];
});

prev_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count--;
  left_image.src = image_array[count - 1];
  right_image.src = image_array[count + 1];
  if (count < 0) {
    count = image_array.length - 1;
  }
  center_image.src = image_array[count];
});
```

Comment: Hi,you can use Owl carousel!!!!https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: As a side note: for looping, the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) is really useful. For instance you could do `count = (count + 1) % image_array.length` to loop the count. You can also use it for the array indices

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code:

```js
next_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  count++;
  left_image.src = image_array[count - 1];

  if (count > image_array.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
  }
  right_image.src = image_array[count + 1];
  center_image.src = image_array[count];
});
```

When you display image 5 as the main image you assign following image sources:

- `left_image.src = image_array[4 - 1]`
- `right_image.src = image_array[4 + 1]`
- `center_image.src = image_array[4]`

However the index `image_array[4+1]` would be the 6th image, which does not exist in the array. You would need to access it at position 0 instead.